# Does $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 1}x\ln(x - 1)$ exist? WolframAlpha says yes

Tags: calculus, limits

The solution to one exercise says that
$$\lim_{x \to 1}x\ln(x - 1) = -\infty$$

How can this be, if $\operatorname{dom} \ln(x - 1) = (1, +\infty)$? Only the limit from the right exists, but the other one does not.

WolframAlpha, however, says that [it exists](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit%20of%20x%20*%20log(x%20-%201)%20for%20x%20-%3E%201). I think the plot is wrong, though.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha shows the complex valued version of $\log$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is defined on $(a,b)$ and is not defined for $x<a$, the right hand limit at $a$ is equal to the limit at $a$.

---

What you wrote in comments is true in this way:

> If $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$, then for each $x_0\in(a,b)$, the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ exists if and only if both directional limits exist.

However, for the limit on $a$ to exist, only the right hand limit needs to exist. This is because the definition of the limit is:

> The limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ is equal to $L$ if, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists such a $\delta > 0$ that for any $x\in \mathrm{dom}(f)$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta$, we have $|f(x)-f(x_0)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: No, my understanding is that it is the other way around: if both directional limits exist, then the limit exist, otherwise it does not. "the limit at $a$" does not exist if the left hand limit does not exist.

Comment: @rubik I edited my answer, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Note the imaginary part (in red) is nonzero: the software chose some branch for the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm), and used that to compute the limit. If you want to stay within the reals, you're right that it's only defined for $x>1$.

Comment: Ah thank you. So in the reals the above limit does not exist.

Comment: Wrong. The $\ln(x-1)$ here is a real function, only defined on $(1,\infty)$, thus the limit exists if and only if the right hand limit exists.

Comment: @5xum [Please learn before making statements like that.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm)

Comment: @NajibIdrissi You are wrong in your last sentence: "If you want to stay within the reals, you're right that it's only defined for $x>1$."

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to say. It's possible to define something called $\ln(x-1)$ for $x \not\in (1,\infty)$, but if you want to keep real valued functions you will have to restrict yourself to $x \in (1,\infty) \iff x > 1$. What's your problem here?

Comment: @5xum What do you think WolframAlpha is displaying here?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I am trying to say that if we consider *only the real part* of the function $x\ln(x-1)$, i.e we look at the function $f: (1, \infty)\to\mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)=x\ln(x-1)$, then this function $f$ has a limit at $1$, and it is equal to $-1$. You do not need to go to complex numbers to calculate the limit.